# How to adjust length of line connecting animated shapes

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I have two shapes (two circles) and a line that connects both. 
Is it possible to keep this connection while the shapes are moving? 
Meaning that the line would move and change size according to the shapes movement?